# Google Cloud IoT core JWT expiration is actually 24 hours?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jwt, iot, google-cloud-iot

Currently I'm programming my device as part of an IoT project with Google Cloud services.

Almost everything is working, but not all. 
I edited the original MQTT library for Python and it started to work correctly if I set the JWT token expiration to less than 2 hours

Is 24 hours a valid expiration time for a JWT token? Or maybe Im doing something wrong?

I'm using Raspberry PI 3B+ and Python 3.6.7

My JWT access and refresh token is the same as the one in the library from Google in Github. My library only runs it in multiple threads so that I could create multiple conections from the same device.

Edit: i modified this line in the `create_jwt` function...

```
'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minute=20)
```

to

```
'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the maximum lifetime of a JWT is 24 hours (plus a little to account for clock skew).

Here's an excerpt from the docs page: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/jwts

> ("Expiration"): The timestamp when the token stops being valid, specified as seconds since 00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970. The maximum lifetime of a token is 24 hours + skew.

Comment: Now i know the maximum lifetime of the token is 24Hours i just fixed my problem changing the `datetime.timedelta(hours=23)` and updating the token each 12H...

Answer (score 2):

One possible cause for this issue is if your Raspberry Pi's clock is set incorrectly. For example, it's possible the system clock is set to local time instead of UTC. Make sure running `date --utc` returns the correct UTC time.

Comment: thats rigth I have the rpi time to the local time, but the issue was in the code mentioned above, for now its working this morning i just leave it running hope its solved now... thanks! ;)